# CS0571 'ResizeSettings.Width.set': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#

I'm trying to construct this method, but get the subject error.

What is the correct format to fix this?

```
ResizeSettings settings1 = new ResizeSettings();
settings1.set_Width(size.Width); // error thrown here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ResizeSettings settings1 = new ResizeSettings();
settings1.Width = size.Width;
```